# How to create a Data Frame in Python from a for loop?

Tags: python, dataframe, prediction

I am trying to merge the results of X with the results of the predicted Y with the help of for loop. How can the result be saved to a DataFrame.

```
predictions = []
for i in range(100):
    predictions.append([X_unseen[i], y_pred_unseen[i]])
print(predictions)

df = pd.Series(predictions)
```

This is the output I get. I am new to Python, so aplogies. Within the [] is a tokenized tweet.

```
0     [['dude', 'adventure', 'time', 'basically', 'r...
1                     [['rape', 'joke'], cyberbullying]
2     [['supporting', 'joke', 'poops', 'faces', 'vic...
3     [['rape', 'joke', 'know', 'serious', 'problem'...
```

I need the following output:

```
x                  y
['rape', 'joke']   cyberbullying
```

Answer (score 0):

You created a `pd.Series` which is basically a single column. If you want multiple columns, you need a whole dataframe.

So instead, do `pd.DataFrame(predictions)`

Comment: Thanks, but pd.DataFrame does not work. I get an error 'tuple' object is not callable. I think, it's the way lists are nested within each other.

Comment: You replaced `pd.Series(predictions)` with `pd.DataFrame(predictions)` and re-ran the code with everything else the same and got that error? That seems strange. The error would come from trying to call a tuple like it is a function or method (like if I had `tup = (1,2); tup()`), which seems like something else in your code is doing that, not the dataframe call. Or is the error actually from` pd.DataFrame(predictions)`?

Comment: Thanks very much! The error is generated from pd.DataFrame(predictions) call. Could this be because the way data in predictions is represented(list within a list)? Maybe it is better to create a list and append there X_unseen, same for y_pred_unseen, and then concatenate these two in a dataframe.Thanks again.

Comment: I think you'll need to update your post with the whole stack trace of the error and what you are running for it. I'm thrown off because the error is saying that a tuple is not callable, but I don't know what tuple you would be trying to call in all of this... I was also able to make a list that I think is the same structure of yours and make a dataframe from it fine: `l = [[[1,2],3],[[4,5],6]]; pd.DataFrame(l)` works fine